# Orchestrating Windows VM on Kubernetes

Tags: windows, kubernetes, orchestration

I am working on Problem statement around Making Windows VM work on Kubernetes , I came across a VM orchestrator on kubernetes https://kubevirt.io . There documentation does not clearly say if it supports Windows ? Any other solution or advise on the same is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create VMs using different operating systems, including Windows.

#### Reference:

http://superuser.openstack.org/articles/kubevirt-kata-containers-vm-use-case/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this set up actually is like a VM (KVM base image) on Linux VM (Kubernetes worker/agent node) , which indirectly means VM inside a VM ?

Comment: Typically for an installation where you are looking to use KubeVirt (for example) to hose a full virtual machine, the Kubernetes cluster itself would be installed on bare-metal. If you are running your Kubernetes cluster on a virtualization platform already, then yes the VMs created by KubeVirt or an equivalent solution would be nested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will find an example template for a Windows Server 2012 image in the KubeVirt tree's examples:

https://github.com/kubevirt/kubevirt/blob/master/cluster/examples/vm-template-windows2012r2.yaml

When Red Hat demonstrated this technology at Red Hat Summit 2018 the image used was actually a Windows guest:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8e4bT0-zhU&t=53m55s

The underlying technology is still the KVM hypervisor, KubeVirt is just orchestrating the userspace components of it (QEMU, Libvirt) in a new way using Kubernetes. Hence for the most part guests that work on existing KVM-based solutions like oVirt, OpenStack, etc. will work on KubeVirt as well.